# Ways to generate gRPC API documentation (specifically for Java, Spring Boot)

Tags: api, grpc, endpoint, documentation-generation, grpc-java

I would like to document the gRPC API in my Spring Boot application. The sources on the web that I have looked through suggest something like mapping endpoints to REST and then generating documentation (e. g. Swagger). I would like to find out if there is a simpler way (without REST) to document gRPC endpoints (something like Swagger), to be able to "automatically" generate the documentation if some changes occur.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I understand the question. I need the same: Something like SpringDoc, but for gRPC. *Without* workarounds, like generating Pesudo-REST interfaces, because getting rid of REST is likely in most cases the whole point of gRPC.